# Puppeteer Set Request Cookie Header

Tags: puppeteer

I'm trying to set the cookies on each request via Puppeteer request interception. I've noticed that while setting `headers['sample-header']=1` creates header 'sample-header' equal to 1, setting `headers['cookie'] = x...` does not set the requests cookie. For instance, the following code does not set any requests cookies.

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false,executablePath:dirnae});
const page = await browser.newPage();
const client = await page.target().createCDPSession();

await page.setRequestInterception(true);

page.on('request', request => {
    const headers = request.headers();
    headers['cookie'] = 1;
    request.continue({ headers });
});

page.on('request', request => {
    console.log(request.headers())
});

page.on('response', response => {
    //console.log(response.headers()['set-cookie'])
});

await page.goto('https://google.com');
```

EDIT: I figured out that I can see the requests cookie header thru handling of the `Network.requestWillBeSentExtraInfo` event.

However, I can't seem to edit requests in that event.

Comment: page.setCookie won't work?

Comment: No, I specifically need to intercept the request and set cookies in there.

Comment: @jamesfdearborn, any specific reason that `page.setCookie` is not acceptable? what is the use cases as such?

Comment: Want to enable multiple logins on the same browser and have to use req interception to set cookies per page.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the cookie per network request. You can use the **page.setCookie** and provide a cookie for different url or domain. Below is the code for reference:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    var cookies = [
        {
            "name": "sample-cookie1",
            "value": "1",
            "domain": "stackoverflow.com"
        },
        {
            "name": "sample-cookie2",
            "value": "2",
            "domain": "pptr.dev"
        }
    ];

    await page.setCookie(...cookies);

    await page.goto("https://pptr.dev");

    console.log(await page.cookies()); //this will have the **sample-cookie2** cookie

    await page.goto("https://stackoverflow.com");

    console.log(await page.cookies()); //this will have the **sample-cookie1** cookie

})();
```